# Make loop data display in two column tailwindcss and Laravel blade layout

Tags: tailwind-css, laravel-blade

I am using tailwind CSS for my laravel/blade views,
I tried grid grid-cols-2 but did not work. I tried the flex types I saw in tailwind css documentation, I seem not to know where to fix. below is what I what to achieve

[image: layout goal]

But currently this is what I get

[image: current layout]

Below is the code now
layout.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <script src="//unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <title>Larame</title>
    <script>
        tailwind.config = {
            theme: {
                extend: {
                    colors: {
                        clifford: '#da373d',
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body class="mb-48">
    <nav class="flex justify-between items-center mb-4">
        <a href="http://localhost/larame/public" class="flex items-center flex-shrink-0 text-amber mr-6">
            <img src="..\public\storage\logo.png" alt="">
            <span class="font-semibold text-xl tracking-tight">Larame</span>
        </a>
        <div class="block lg:hidden">
            <button class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 border rounded text-black-200 border-black-400 hover:text-amber hover:border-amber">
                <svg class="fill-current h-3 w-3" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>Menu</title><path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z"/></svg>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="block flex-grow lg:flex lg:items-center lg:w-auto">
            <ul class="text-sm lg:flex-grow block flex-grow lg:flex lg:items-center lg:w-auto">
                <li>
                    <a href="#responsive-header" class="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-black-200 hover:text-amber mr-4">
                        Docs
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#responsive-header" class="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-black-200 hover:text-amber mr-4">
                        Examples
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#responsive-header" class="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-black-200 hover:text-amber">
                        Blog
                    </a>
                </li>
                
            </ul>
            <div>
                @auth
                {{-- this is only displayed when the user is authenticated --}}
                <a href="http://localhost/larame/public/register" class="text-sm px-4 py-2 font-bold"><span>
                    Welcome {{auth()->user()->name}}</span></a>
                <a href="http://localhost/larame/public/listings/manage" class="inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded text-amber border-amber hover:border-transparent hover:text-black-500 hover:bg-amber mt-4 lg:mt-0">Manage Listings</a>
                <a href="" class="inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded text-amber border-amber hover:border-transparent hover:text-black-500 hover:bg-amber mt-4 lg:mt-0">
                    <form action="http://localhost/larame/public/logout" method="post" class="inline">
                    @csrf
                    <button type="submit" >
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-door-closed">Logout</i>
                    </button>
                    </form>
                </a>
                @else
                {{-- This is dispalayed when the user is NOT authenticated --}}
                <a href="http://localhost/larame/public/register" class="inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded text-amber border-amber hover:border-transparent hover:text-black-500 hover:bg-amber mt-4 lg:mt-0">Signup</a>
                <a href="http://localhost/larame/public/login" class="inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded text-amber border-amber hover:border-transparent hover:text-black-500 hover:bg-amber mt-4 lg:mt-0">Login</a>
                @endauth
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <main>
        {{-- VIEW OUTPUT --}}
        {{-- @yield('content') --}}
        {{$slot}}
    </main>
    <!--Footer container-->
    <footer class="bg-black py-4 fixed bottom-0 left-0 w-full flex items-center justify-start font-bold bg-laravel text-white h-24 mt-24 opacity-90 md:justify-center">
            <div>
                <a class="justify-end text-yellow-300 right-2.5 bg-black border border-2 border-yellow-300 hover:bg-yellow-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 py-2 dark:border-yellow-300 dark:hover:bg-yellow-300 hover:text-black" href="http://localhost/larame/public/listings/create">
                    Post a job
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <x-flash-message />
</body>
</html>
```

card-listing.blade.php

```
@props(['listing'])
<x-card>
    <div class="flex">
        <img class="hidden w-48 mr-6 md:block"
        src="{{$listing->logo ? asset('storage/'.$listing->logo) : asset('../storage/app/public/web-icon.PNG')}}" alt="" />
        <div>
                  <h3 class="text-2xl">
                      <a href="http://localhost/larame/public/listings/{{$listing->id}}">{{$listing->title}}</a>
                  </h3>
                  <div class="text-xl font-bold mb-4">{{$listing->company}}</div>
                    <x-listing-tags :tagsCsv="$listing->tags" />
                  <div class="text-lg mt-4">
                      <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i> {{$listing->location}}
                  </div>
            </div>
          </div>
</x-card>
```

card.blade.php

```
<div {{$attributes->merge(['class' => 'bg-gray-50 border border-gray-200 rounded p-5'])}}>
  {{$slot}}
</div>
```

I have tried several things but still not working. I will appreciate some help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `'w-fit'` to the `card.blade.php` to prevent it from taking the fall width ,
Also try wrapping all your cards in a `div` with the classes `grid grid-cols-2 gap-2`
That should work

Comment: Thanks for your response. This suggestion separates the content of each item, ie the image is on one column while the attached text goes far to the other column

Comment: @chized I mean you could try `grid` if this doesn't work,  wrap your cards inside a div with `grid grid-cols-2 gap-4`, That would 100% work but unfortunately I don't see where you are looping over the listing,  if you add more code that would be helpful,  or I can just give you a link to play tailwindcss example for both grid and flex

Comment: @chized Where are you using `card-listing.blade`? Add the code for that